# How to interpret the negative (actual) evapotranspiration values?

Tags: meteorology, hydrology, evaporation, water-vapour

I am exploring FLUXNET sites for actual evapotranspiration (ETP) data (I convert the energy balance closure-corrected latent heat to ETP).

I am interested in the half-hourly data. During the night we see negative values. I would like to know the reason or physical process behind this.

Can physically-based hydrological models handle this situation? (: estimating negative half-hourly ETPs)

There are some discussion in web about how to handle the negative values of potential ETP, but not easy to find a solid discussion about the actual ETP in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Negative values for the ET, both potential and actual, usually refer to [condensation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation).
See also "[ERA5 mean evaporation rates data - Why is that negative?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/17839/era5-mean-evaporation-rates-data-why-is-that-negative/17854#17854)"

Regarding the ability of the physically-based hydrological models to handle condensation, I'd say that it's difficult to give you a general answer: it will depend on the specific math behind the model, but my general guess would be that they do.
Even a simple [Bucket Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Tank_Model.jpg), would integrate condensation in the [water balance equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Water_balance). While a more sophisticate Earth System Model would probably process it in the soil moisture and/or canopy component, in order to better represent these dynamics in the water-energy balance of the specific system. See for instance [Longo et al 2019](https://gmd.copernicus.org/articles/12/4309/2019/gmd-12-4309-2019.pdf)